# enqueuing Bootstrap to Wordpress with functions.php

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code in my functions.php folder (using a Child theme, if that factors anything here)

```
<?php
function theme_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');

function theme_js() {

    global $wp_scripts;

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap.min.js' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');

?>
```

Using FTP, I have added the bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js folders to my child theme directory (downloaded from the site).

However, when i go to do an accordion on a code block in a page I am building, it doesn't create the accordion. The code is below:

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
            </h4>
        </div></div></div>
```

All that happens is it displays the text, with a link.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked any console errors in your browser? If the JS is being called at all?Or later than needed, etc.

Comment: This is a well written question from a new StackOverflow user. Great example of posting relevant code and writing the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_template_directory_uri()` returns the directory of the parent theme. In order to get the child theme directory you should use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

**Note:** `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` Does not contain a trailing slash.

So in your `wp_enqueue_*` lines swap `get_template_directory_uri()` for `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and you should no longer have a 404 provided the rest of the file path is correct, and that the file is indeed on the server.

Comment: That worked! Why does this only need to be applied to the bootstrap.min.css and not the bootstrap.min.js?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. It would need to be applied to both the JS and CSS enqueues if both files in the child theme.